# PHP contact form with multiple recipient not working

Tags: php, html, contact-form

I have built a PHP contact form where a user has to fill in all the fields, validates the form in php and sends to the previous chosen recipient. Unfortunately it is not working, the message never gets to it's destination. What am I doing wrong?

**I leave you with the code:**

```
<form method="post" action="index.php#kontakt">
    <p>
    <label>Namn</label>
    <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Skriv här">

    <label>Din e-post adress</label>
    <input name="dinepost" type="email" placeholder="Skriv här">

    <label for="sendTo">Välj mottagare:</label>
    <select name="sendTo" required id="sendTo">
        <option id="joao" value="joao">joao</option>
        <option id="company 2" value="lfsolutions">lfsolutions</option>
    </select>

    <label>Meddelande</label>
    <textarea name="message" placeholder="Skriv här"></textarea>

    <label>Hur mycket är 2+2? (Anti-spam)</label>
    <input name="human" type="number" placeholder="Svara här">
    </p>
    <p>
    <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Skicka meddelandet!" class="botao"><br>
    *Alla fält är obligatoriska
    </p>
    <?php
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['dinepost'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];
        $from = 'webbsida'; 
        $to = $_POST['sendTo'];
        $subject = 'Ny meddelande';
        $human = $_POST['human'];

        switch ($sendTo) {
            case "joao":
              $sendTo = "email1@gmail.com";
              break;
            case "lfsolutions":
              $sendTo = "email2@gmail.com";
              break;

            default:
              $sendTo = "email3@gmail.com";
        }

        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL;
        $headers .= "From: $from <$email> ". PHP_EOL;
        $headers .= "Content-type: text/html;charset=UTF-8 ". PHP_EOL;

        $name = str_replace( '[at]','@', $name);
        $message = str_replace( '[at]','@', $message);

        $body = "<strong>Från:</strong> $name\n <br><strong>E-post:</strong> $dinepost\n <br><strong>Meddelandet:</strong>\n <br>$message";

        if ($_POST['submit']) {
        if ($name != '' && filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            if ($human == '4') {                 
                if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) { 
                echo '<div data-alert class="alert-box success">
                        <p>Ditt meddelande har skickats! Tack så mycket!</p>
                        <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>
                      </div>';
            } else { 
                echo '<div data-alert class="alert-box alert">
                        <p>Någonting gick fel. Var vänlig och försök igen!</p>
                        <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>
                      </div>'; 
            } 
        } else if ($_POST['submit'] && $human != '4') {
            echo '<div data-alert class="alert-box alert">
                    <p>Du har gett fel svar på Anti-Spam frågan!</p>
                    <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>
                  </div>';
        }
        } else {
            echo '<div data-alert class="alert-box alert">
                    <p>Du behöver att fylla alla fält i formuläret!</p>
                    <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>
                  </div>';
        }
    }

    ?>
</form>
```

Comment: `Unfortunately it is not working` In what way is it not working? Are you getting an error? If so, what is the message? Is it sending to some but not all recipients, or none at all? Have you tried a minimal example that just calls the `mail` function to make sure that it is not an issue with your configuration? Please add sufficient detail, thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry, you are right, I have already corrected my question

Comment: you mean the email is not sending ??

Comment: What happens if you run  a script that just calls `mail` w/ a test message? Does the email reach its destination then?

Comment: I presume the e-mail is sending because I go get the message that the message has been sent. @BrianDriscoll, sorry?

Comment: I'm trying to help you isolate the issue by running a _different_ script that has a single line: `mail('email1@gmail.com', 'Test message', 'Test message');` in order to verify that your mail configuration is not the cause of the issue.

Comment: Not that I am not accepting your help but I know that the form works without the switch statement because I have it working on other websites

Comment: Is there a way to get some kind of system output so that one gets an eventual error message?

Comment: @viriato Other websites on the same server, using the same php.ini?

Comment: The only reason I'm pushing you to do this test is because whenever `mail` is involved 9/10 times it's a config issue and/or there is a config issue in addition to a script issue.

Comment: No, not on the same server, not yet at least

Comment: @BrianDriscoll I took out the switch statement and the form is working. I get the message right away, so I don't think it is a php.ini problem

Answer (score 0):

Your switch statement is the problem.
if i understand your code correctly it should be

```
switch ($to) {    // not $sendTo
   // (...)
          }
```

Your version does not respect the user's selection.

Does that help you?

Comment: Good catch, but in that case the email should still be going to the address specified in the `default` case.

Comment: Yes, that was in deed wrong but it is still not working :/ I don't get the messages on my e-mail box...

Comment: Brian Driscoll is right: try sending an email via a simple test script. if that does not reach you, find out why that is. Check your php.ini, for example.

Comment: I took out the switch statement and the form is working. I get the message right away, so I don't think it is a php.ini problem

Comment: i noticed one more thing:
if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $headers))
sends to $to, not $sendTo. If you still work with the above code, that would need fixing.

Comment: @Burki, see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

So you actually have two issues. First is the switch issue that was pointed out by Burki.

The second is that you are not using the value of `$sendTo` when you call mail. Your call to `mail` needs to use `$sendTo` for the To: field, as such:

```
mail ($sendTo, $subject, $body, $headers)
```

Comment: I tried that, did not work, I was still getting the success message but no e-mail on my mail box. So, I added instead mail ($sendTo, $to, $subject, $body, $headers) and it works but now the $from is replaced by some server name on the sender fidl on my Gmail and the html I have on the message body is not rendered, I can see all the markup as plain text :(

Comment: The signature for `mail` is: `bool mail ( string $to , string $subject , string $message [, string $additional_headers [, string $additional_parameters ]] )`, so when you call `mail ($sendTo, $to, $subject, $body, $headers)` you are putting `$to` as the subject, `$subject` as the body, `$body` as additional headers, and `$headers` as additional parameters. Doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: Also, for `$headers` are you certain that the `PHP_EOL` constant value is "\r\n"? That is what is needed for headers, so if `PHP_EOL` has a value of "\n" for instance then your headers aren't being sent properly.